# redirect non www to www and rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In fact, I am working on a small PHP script. I created some rules to redirect nonwww to www version here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule app-([0-9]+)\.html app.html?id=$1 [L,QSA] 
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

It works fine when redirecting the home page but when i want to redirect site.com/app-9.html for example it just redirect to the www version like this :
www.site.com/app.html?id=9.
It should redirect site.com/app-9.html to www.site.com/app-9.html. How can I achieve this please ?

pass:

> site.com/app-9.html

current result:

> www.site.com/app.html?id=9

required result:

> www.site.com/app-9.html

Comment: why are you add `RewriteRule app-([0-9]+)\.html app.html?id=$1 [L,QSA]`, if not required.

Comment: @RohitGoyani Please check the updated version !

Comment: You should remove `RewriteRule app-([0-9]+)\.html app.html?id=$1 [L,QSA]` if not required. After that working fine.

Comment: @RohitGoyani It is required :)

Comment: Can we stop this rule for `app-9.html` only? means it will never redirect on `app.html?id=9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added validation for app-9.html only, Becuase the rule is required for others.

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

## added validation for app-9.html only
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !app-9.html -f
RewriteRule app-([0-9]+)\.html app.html?id=$1 [L,QSA] 

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert

> RewriteRule ^/page /page?

into your rewrite rule? This will remove the query string altogether.